# How many stories are contained in Asimov's "The Complete Robot"?

Tags: short-stories, isaac-asimov, the-complete-robot

I am wondering how many stories are contained in Isaac Asimov's "The Complete Robot"?

Comment: [_"The Complete Robot (1982) is a collection of **31 of the 37** science fiction short stories about robots by American writer Isaac Asimov"_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Complete_Robot) - is that what you need?

Comment: Yes, that answers my question! Thank you!

Comment: I did a quick delve of ISFDB and indeed, it looks like it's the same count for all editions they have.

Comment: FuzzyBoots, thank you, it didn't occur to me that there might've been different amounts of stories in different editions. Glad that they seem to remain constant, that makes my life much easier!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The go-to resource for such questions is [Jenkins’ Spoiler-Laden Guide to Isaac Asimov](http://www.asimovreviews.net/).  This guide has cataloged all books and all stories written by Asmiov.

In this case, [the page about *The Complete Robot*](http://www.asimovreviews.net/Books/Book249.html) lists all **31** stories of the volume:

#### Some non-human robots

- “A Boy’s Best Friend”
- “Sally”
- “Someday”

#### Some immobile robots

- “Point of View”
- “Think!”
- “True Love”

#### Some metallic robots

- “Robot AL-76 Goes Astray”
- “Victory Unintentional”
- “Stranger In Paradise”
- “Light Verse”
- “Segregationist”
- “Robbie” aka “Strange Playfellow”

#### Some humanoid robots

- “Let’s Get Together”
- “Mirror Image”
- “The Tercentenary Incident”

#### Powell and Donovan

- “First Law”
- “Runaround”
- “Reason”
- “Catch That Rabbit”

#### Susan Calvin

- “Liar!”
- “Satisfaction Guaranteed”
- “Lenny”
- “Galley Slave”
- “Little Lost Robot”
- “Risk”
- “Escape!” aka “Paradoxical Escape”
- “Evidence”
- “The Evitable Conflict”
- “Feminine Intuition”

#### Two Climaxes

- “-That Thou Art Mindful of Him”
- “The Bicentennial Man”

(Flq provided The headings from a paperback-copy in English bought probably in the early 00s, ISBN 0-586-05724-2.)

Answer (score 3):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Complete_Robot),

> *The Complete Robot* (1982) is a collection of 31 of the 37 science fiction short stories about robots by American writer Isaac Asimov, [...]

The stories *not* included are listed in that article as well; they are

> - "Robot Dreams" (found in the anthology of the same title)
> - "Robot Visions" (found in the anthology of the same title)
> - "Too Bad!" (found in *Robot Visions*)
> - "Christmas Without Rodney" (found in *Robot Visions*)
> - "Cal" (found in *Gold*)
> - "Kid Brother" (found in *Gold*)

Answer (score 3):

As other said, 31. Plus an introduction, last word and short introduction to each of the 7 sections. See the below images of the contents page of the book for evidence:

[image: Asimov: The Complete Robot front cover]

[image: Asimov: The Complete Robot contents page 1]

[image: Asimov: The Complete Robot contents page 2]